# Правильно ли я оформил код? C#

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, оформление

Я сделал свою программу, которая решает уравнения. Я сделал проверку: сложения(+), разности(-), произведения(*) и частности(/). В входные данные входят: число, оператор, икс, равно, результат. Я долго писал программу, так как я ещё тренируюсь. Он у меня полностью работает! Но у меня возник вопрос, годен ли мой код? Можно ли его как-то улучшить? Есть ли с ним проблемы(скорее всего). Надеюсь вы мне поможете пожалуйста. Мой код:

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static string GetResult(string primer)
        {
            var split = primer.Split(' ');
            var xPosition = Array.IndexOf(split, "x");

            var Result = Convert.ToInt32(split[split.Length - 1]);

            var OtherDigit = xPosition == 0 ? int.Parse(split[2]) : int.Parse(split[0]);
            
            // Console.WriteLine(xPosition + " --- is position");
            var _operator = Convert.ToChar(split[1]);
            switch (_operator)
            {
                case '+':
                    return $"x = {Result} - {OtherDigit}\n" +
                           $"x = {Result - OtherDigit}";
                case '-':
                    return xPosition == 0 ? $"x = {Result} + {OtherDigit}\n " + $"x = {Result + OtherDigit}" : 
                        $"x = {OtherDigit} - {Result}\n" + $"x = {OtherDigit - Result}";
                case '*':
                    return $"x = {Result} / {OtherDigit}\n" +
                           $"x = {Result / OtherDigit}";
                case '/':
                    return xPosition == 0 ? $"x = {OtherDigit} * {Result}\n" + $"x = {OtherDigit * Result}" : 
                        $"x = {OtherDigit} / {Result}\n" + $"x = {OtherDigit / Result}";
            }
            return "Err0r, s0rry. :(";
        }
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите пример: ");
            var primer = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(primer);
            Console.WriteLine(GetResult(primer));

            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите на любую клавишу чтобы выйти ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

И если что, как тут код записан, так и он записан у меня в JetBrains Rider.

Comment: Чисто небольшая придирка. Рас уж используете тернарный оператор, то думаю лучше например в `case '/'` написать его в 2 строчки хотя бы. Где 1 строчка это, что произойдет если true а на 2 строчке иначе. Так читать думаю удобней будет

Comment: @ПавелЕриков тоже самое мне сделать и с `case '-'`?

Comment: Ну конечно xd )

Comment: Ну, Спасибо xd)

Comment: Я бы сказал тут много чего можно улучшить, ибо на данный момент это непонятная каша. Например, почему у вас и `.Parse()` и `Convert` используется? Почему вы в одном методе реализуете логику сложения, вычитания, деления и так далее, следуйте базовым правилам, как минимум SRP, где каждый метод должен отвечать за что-то одно. Плюс к этому, почему `GetResult` вдруг дает строку, а не вычисления вашей формулы? Также я не пойму, почему вы разбиваете все по пробелу, это ведь неудобно, ибо человек будет писать `1+1`, а не `1 + 1`, а в вашем случае, первый вариант выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 1. Я исправил, и теперь везде использую `.Parse()`
2. Я думал что в одном методе я сделаю всю логику моей программы. Могу исправить ради читабельности.
3. Программа выдаёт сами вычисления.
4. Я ещё не знаю, как числа разбить без пробела, поэтому использую с пробелами.

А так, спасибо за обратную связь моего кода ;3

Comment: @A_Br2H Почитайте про рефакторинг. Метод не должен быть сплошной простынёй непонятного кода. Лучше много небольших методов, когда понятно, что каждый из них делает. Вынесите "магические константы" из кода. Разделите вычисления и отображение. Это для начала.

Comment: Повесил метку [tag:инспекция-кода], так что можно даже и полноценный ответ всем писать что где не так.......а не в комментариях)) @CrazyElf ↑

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ↑ %))

Comment: Наименование локальных переменных должно быть единообразным - все они должны начинаться со строчной буквы, а у вас сплошной разнобой: `split, Result, _operator`. Нижнее подчеркивание используется для наименования приватных полей классов, заглавная в начале названий Классов, Методов, Свойств, Событий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень качественно у вас намешано. Чем однотипнее оформлен код, тем проще он читается, а соответственно его легче изменить или объяснить другому разработчику, что он делает.

Я не стал трогать логику вашего решения, оставил все как есть, но изменил именно оформление кода.

- Правила именования переменных нарушены. Локальные переменные должны называться с маленькой буквы.
- Перемешана конкантенация и интерполяция строк, надо выбрать что-то одно.
- Вы форматируете выходную строку по одним и тем же правилам каждый раз, почему бы не вынести повторяющийся код в отдельный метод?
- Тернарный оператор тем и хорош, что его можно засунуть насколько угодно глубоко в строчку кода и бонус от этого - убирание повторяющегося кода.

Следите за руками, каждая последующая строчка лучше предыдущей

```cs
var OtherDigit = xPosition == 0 ? int.Parse(split[2]) : int.Parse(split[0]);
var OtherDigit = int.Parse(xPosition == 0 ? split[2]: split[0]);
var OtherDigit = int.Parse(split[xPosition == 0 ? 2 : 0]);
var OtherDigit = int.Parse(split[xPosition ^ 2]);
```

По поводу `^` - это побитовая операция XOR, вы же проходили двоичные операции `&`, `|`, `^`? Должны были, а если нет - [самое время начать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators).

Переменные, давайте переименуемся:

- `split` - когда что-то разделяется на части, это называется токены - `tokens`.
- `xPosition` - почему `x`? у вас же нет никаких других позишнов - просто `position`.
- `Result` - здесь вообще нет логики, операнды в выражении из 2 операндов называются левый и правый, пусть жто будет левый - `left`.
- `OtherDigit` - "ДругаяЦифра" почему цифра, почему другая... - `right`
- `_operator` - здесь логика есть, вы назвали так, потому что ключевое слово `operator` нельзя использовать для названия переменной, но вы используете эту переменную всего один раз, значит можно вообще без нее обойтись. Кстати, чтобы получить первый символ строки, можно обратиться к нему по индексу `[0]`, вот и получится, что `var _operator = Convert.ToChar(split[1])` можно было бы записать как `var _operator = split[1][0]`
- `primer` - транслит, хуже транслита только кириллица. Также у вас же уравнение с одной неизвестной, вот давайте это так и назовем "уравнение" - `equation`.
- `GetResult()` - "получить результат", неплохо, но можно лучше. "вычислить" - `Compute()`

`Err0r, s0rry. :(` - как пользователь поймет, что случилось по этой надписи? Вы встречали приложения, которые вам выдают окошко с надписью `Произошла ошибка`, и больше ничего не выдают? Вот и я не встречал, встречал только `Произошла неизвестная ошибка`, но это уже другая история. Потом для генерации ошибок есть такая штука - исключения, их можно бросать `throw` и ловить `catch`.

```cs
private static string Compute(string equation)
{
    var tokens = equation.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (tokens.Length != 5)
        throw new Exception("Неподдерживаемый формат уравнения");
    var position = Array.IndexOf(tokens, "x");

    var left = int.Parse(tokens[tokens.Length - 1]);
    var right = int.Parse(tokens[position ^ 2]);

    switch (tokens[1][0])
    {
        case '+':
            return Format(left, right, '-', left - right);
        case '-':
            return position == 0 
                ? Format(left, right, '+', left + right)
                : Format(right, left, '-', left - right);
        case '*':
            return Format(left, right, '/', left / right);
        case '/':
            return position == 0 
                ? Format(right, left, '*', right * left)
                : Format(right, left, '/', right / left);
        default:
            throw new Exception("Неизвестный оператор");
    }
}

private static string Format(int left, int right, char action, int result)
{
    return $"x = {left} {action} {right}\nx = {result}";
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите уравнение: ");
    var equation = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(equation);
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Compute(equation));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Ошибка: {ex.Message}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Нажмите на любую клавишу чтобы выйти ...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

А если вы пишете код на C# 8.0 или новее, то есть под .NET Core или .NET 5, то есть более свежий и компактный синтаксис, и метод `Compute()` может выглядеть вот так:

```cs
private static string Compute(string primer)
{
    var tokens = primer.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (tokens.Length != 5)
        throw new Exception("Неподдерживаемый формат уравнения");
    var position = Array.IndexOf(tokens, "x");

    var left = int.Parse(tokens[^1]); // ^1 - последний элемент, ^2 - предпоследний и т.д.
    var right = int.Parse(tokens[position ^ 2]); // а это XOR, не перепутайте

    return tokens[1][0] switch
    {
        '+' => Format(left, right, '-', left - right),
        '-' => position == 0 ? Format(left, right, '+', left + right) : Format(right, left, '-', left - right),
        '*' => Format(left, right, '/', left / right),
        '/' => position == 0 ? Format(right, left, '*', right * left) : Format(right, left, '/', right / left),
        _ => throw new Exception("Неизвестный оператор"),
    };
}
```

`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` удалит все пустые элементы при разделении строки, они могли возникнуть, если у вас где-то в уравнении вместо одного - например 2 пробела, или больше. То есть каждый элемент массива `tokens` теперь будет гарантированно не пустой.

Comment: Все бы не плохо, только вот пропаганда c#8+... Почти в каждом ответе, это ведь просто синтаксический сахар, не более. IL код же вроде бы не отличается от того же обычного switch/case,

Comment: @mik.ov `async/await` - тоже сахар.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам, очень хороший ответ. Сейчас надо будет разобраться с каждым участком и по практиковаться с ним чтобы запомнить) Ещё раз спасибо.