# Парсер мат. операции в уравнении

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, математика

Столкнулся с банальной проблемой парсера математического уравнения. Собсно, есть код на c#, задача которого решение математического уравнения, и для этого он парсит каждую математическую операцию, по типу a+b с наличием переменной х и возможными степенями, целого или дробного числа, отрицательного и положительного числа.

Вот пример парсера операции вычисления:

```
reg = new Regex(@"(([-+]?)(((\d+)((\,(\d+))?)((x((\^(\d+))?))?))|(x((\^(\d+))?))((\/(((\d+)((\,(\d+))?)((x((\^(\d+))?))?))|(x((\^(\d+))?))))?))(((-)([-+]?)(((\d+)((\,(\d+))?)((x((\^(\d+))?))?))|(x((\^(\d+))?)))((\/(((\d+)((\,(\d+))?)((x((\^(\d+))?))?))|(x((\^(\d+))?))))?))))");
```

Со своей задачей справляется, если на входе будет уравнение с искомой операцией не идущей подряд, то есть a-b или a-b+c-d. В таком случае, он спарсит a-b в первом случае или a-b и c-d во втором.
Но когда встречается a-b-c, спарсится только первое соответствие. То есть, я понимаю, что регулярные выражения продолжают искать соответствия начиная с того места, после предыдущего найденого соответствия. НО все же, можно ли как то заставить поиск искать все возможные соответствия. Или гибкие регулярные выражения не настолько гибкие?

PS хотелось бы, конечно, по возможности допилить именно этот шаблон, иначе придется переделывать функции, что очень лень. Но если иначе никак, то что уж поделать...

Comment: Вам точно тут регулярки нужны?

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688781/179763

Comment: Что-то мне кажется похожего здесь совсем нет. Регулярки нужны, так как в программе на входе есть строка с неким математическим уравнением, которое пользователь вбивает сам. Например, вбивает 2x-5-9=0 и тд. Ну и логично, как мне показалось, что проще это дело регулярками обрабатывать...

Comment: если вас именно интересует, как это делается по нормальному, то можно глядеть в сторону [сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), разбирать выражение в абстрактное синтаксическое дерево и там уже делать с ним все, что угодно. Разбирать выражение регуляркой - у вас тогда постоянно какие то трудности будут с разбором выражения.

Comment: По-моему, это нереально, особенно если учесть всяческие скобки, например... Мне кажется, тогда уж проще синтаксический анализатор написать. Кстати, как всегда, вопрос - зачем? Что вы потом с этим выражением делаете? Не просто же останавливаетесь на этом — вот, введено верное выражение...?

Comment: Ну, хоть что-то. Будем смотреть в сторону этой станции, хотя времени на это не так много.

Comment: В своей программе я как раз решил опустить пока работу со скобками, чтобы хоть немного упростить себе задачу. Зачем все это? Задание для практики - написать калькулятор линейного уравнения. Сейчас я менешь всего парюсь насчет того нормально ли или правильно написано - нужно поскорее закончить с этим закончить.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1243329/373567

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен со всеми комментариями относительно подходов к решению, и возможно этот ответ не уместен. Но если мы говорим о частном случае разбора простых уравнений, без скобок, то мне просто больно смотреть на вашу регулярку.

Я бы использовал [одно выражение](https://regex101.com/r/LYLSYs/1) для проверки корректности ввода уравнения, а [второе](https://regex101.com/r/LYLSYs/3) для выделения членов уравнения.

Код на JS для демонстрации работы РВ:

```js
check.onclick = () => {
  clearGrid();

  let value = equation.value.replaceAll(' ', '');
  let check = /^(?:[-+*\/]?\b(?:\d+x?|x))+=(?:[-+*\/]?\b(?:\d+x?|x))+$/.test(value);

  if (check) {
    let matches = value.matchAll(/(=)()()|([-+*\/]?)(?:(\d+)(x?)|()(x))/mg);
    for (const m of matches) {
      let data = m.filter(v => v !== undefined);
      data.every(v => grid.innerHTML += `<span class="m">${v}</span>`);
    };
  } else {
    console.log('Уравнение задано с ошибками!');
  }
}

function clearGrid() {
  let cells = [...document.querySelectorAll('.m')];
  cells.every(v => v.remove() || true);
}
```

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: min-content;
}

#grid span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<input id="equation" type="text" value="3x + 5 - 9 = 10x + 7 - x" />
<button id="check">Проверить</button>
<div id="grid">
  <span>member</span>
  <span>sign</span>
  <span>value</span>
  <span>variable</span>
</div>
```

Как получить эти группы на С#:

```
string pattern  = @"(=)()()|([-+*\/]?)(?:(\d+)(x?)|()(x))";
string input    = @"3x+5-9=-10x+7-x";

string[] names  = { "member", "sign", "value", "variable" };

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        if(m.Groups[i].Success)
            Console.WriteLine(names[index++ % 4] + ": " + m.Groups[i].Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно разбить на массив

```
String myString = "a+b-c*d/e";
String[] result=myString.split("[-+*/]");
```

И дальше уже работать с массивом, и также забрать массив оператором

Возможно костыль, но и задача довольно не тривиальная

Comment: Так знаки теряются. Если идти путем разбиения строки, то все равно через регулярное выражение (`RegEx.Split()`).

Comment: я описал , что это первая операция, второй мы забираем только буквы , и у нас на выходе есть два массива. Первый с операторами по их последовательности, второй с переменными. Дальше надо просто пробежать по массиву операторов и определить их порядок выполнения , и тд ..